# Simple test code for Lucene 4.3.0 doesn't work

Tags: java, apache, testing, lucene

I wrote simple code based on book "Lucene in action" which should show me how work different analyzers (with Lucene 4.3.0). But when I try to increment tokenStream, then I receive NullPointerException. Do you have any suggestions? Below I attach the code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("\n----");
    System.out.println("StandardAnalyzer");
    displayTokensWithFullDetails(new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43),
        "I'll email you at xyz@example.com");
}

public static void displayTokensWithFullDetails(Analyzer analyzer,
                                                  String text) throws IOException {

    TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("contents",
                                              new StringReader(text));

    //defining attributes

    while(stream.incrementToken()) {

      //print details of tokens

    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

I can't start a loop. Do you have idea what am I doing wrong?

Here I add stacktrace:

```
----
StandardAnalyzer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at           org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.zzRefill(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:923)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.getNextToken(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:1133)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.incrementToken(StandardTokenizer.java:171)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardFilter.incrementToken(StandardFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter.incrementToken(LowerCaseFilter.java:54)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.FilteringTokenFilter.incrementToken(FilteringTokenFilter.java:50)
at AnalyzerUtils.displayTokensWithFullDetails(AnalyzerUtils.java:115)
at AnalyzerUtils.main(AnalyzerUtils.java:169)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found solution. After initiation of TokenStream, StandardTokenizationImpl don't receive Reader object but receive null. When we type reset() on the stream StandardTokenizationImpl wiil receive finally our Stream. So my code should like as below:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("\n----");
    System.out.println("StandardAnalyzer");
    displayTokensWithFullDetails(new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43),
        "I'll email you at xyz@example.com");
}

public static void displayTokensWithFullDetails(Analyzer analyzer,
                                                  String text) throws IOException {

    TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("contents",
                                              new StringReader(text));

    stream.reset(); //Add this line removes NullPointerException

    //defining attributes

    while(stream.incrementToken()) {

      //print details of tokens

    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

Comment: Might be helpful to take a look at the [TokenStream spec](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html), which provides a step-by-step workflow on how to use TokenStream correctly.

Comment: Dosent work :     java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.
I get a different exception now stated above. Please post information correctly.